# How do I change the order in which login items execute under OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, user-account, login-items

If I remember right, in earlier versions of OS X, it was possible to "drag-and-drop" to rearrange Login Items so that they start in a different order.

Under OS X 10.8.2 this doesn't seem to work. Short of deleting all the entries, then re-adding them by hand in the new order I want, how else can I conveniently re-order them?

I don't see why Apple would intentionally remove this feature, maybe it's a bug. I'm not too interested in weird work-arounds like external Automator or Applescript scripts with custom delays, etc. Hoping there's just some little thing I'm overlooking.

Here's a screencap of the window I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: The order of items in the list is mostly 'cosmetic'?  All items start roughly together.  Do you want to control startup order or just the cosmetics?

Answer (score 1):

I use TinkerTool (free) to handle that little job.

http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html

Comment: While TinkerTool used to do this it no longer does.  The Version 5.1 release notes explain:

*The pane Login Items has been removed because it is no longer useful for the latest operating system versions. Modern OS X installations start the items simultaneously, independent of their visible order, and also use additional mechanisms such as Resume and invisible launch entries which have influence on the start sequence during the login phase*

http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/history.html

Answer (score 0):

I have given up trying to control Login Items in the standard way.  DelayedLauncher allows you to control the order in which items are started and to inserts delays. [DelayedLauncher V2](http://www.taoeffect.com/blog/2010/03/delayedlauncher-2-0/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. DelayedLauncher looks like it hasn't been updated since OS X 10.4 & 2010, I don't plan to risk installing it on my machine.

Comment: Last updated in 2011, DelayedLauncher continues to work well with Lion and Mountain Lion.  And its free!