# Sort load of login items

Tags: macos, login-items

I have about 20 login items in my profile, and I often can use Alfred from the very beginning stage of the system start, but sometimes not. Will be great if I can say the system to load Alfred first and then the others.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: The only way I've found is to remove them & add back in the required order - which isn't ideal, so I'm hoping someone has a solution too :)

Answer (score 1):

> Modern OS X installations start the items simultaneously, independent of their visible order, and also use additional mechanisms such as Resume and invisible launch entries which have influence on the start sequence during the login phase.

From: http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/history.html

See:

- [How do I change the order in which login items execute under OS X 10.8.2?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83106/how-do-i-change-the-order-in-which-login-items-execute-under-os-x-10-8-2)
- [How to control order of startup items for users at login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122431/how-to-control-order-of-startup-items-for-users-at-login)